# How to add date automatically based on the user input in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I am pretty new to Datetime and pandas. I want to add new date row based on the given value. If the input is 2 then the program should two dates from the last row value. I could able to get the dates but I Am not able to insert them into the data frame. Here the Date is an index. Is there any way to do it?

My input:

```
df=
            column1
2020-12-22    1
2020-12-23    2
2020-12-24    3
start = df.index.max()
numdays =4
date_list = [start - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(numdays)]
date_list
```

The output is as follows:

```
[Timestamp('2020-12-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-12-25 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-12-26 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2020-12-27 00:00:00')]
```

Expected Output:

```
    column1
2020-12-22    1
2020-12-23    2
2020-12-24    3
2020-12-25    Naan
2020-12-26    Naan
2020-12-27    Naan
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do so :

```
import datetime as dt
delta = int(input('Enter the number of row'))
for i in range(delta):
    df.loc[df.index[-1]+dt.timedelta(days=1)] = np.nan
df
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

As I didn't understand if you want a real input, I've coded it, but if not, you just have to assign your value to ‘delta‘ without asking via input

```
import datetime as dt
delta = 2
for i in range(delta):
    df.loc[df.index[-1]+dt.timedelta(days=1)] = np.nan
df
```